# Set srcset on a block image

Tags: plugin-development, images, block-editor

I'm trying to set the `srcset` property of a block image.
I'm replacing the image with another one and I noticed the attribute `srcset` is not being set, so I'm trying this with no success:

```js
wp.data.dispatch('core/block-editor').updateBlock(blockId, {
    attributes: {
        id: imageData.id,
        url: imageData.url,
        srcset: imageData.srcset,
    },
});
```

Am I missing something?

The image gets displayed like this on post, without the `srcset` attribute for different resolutions:

```html
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img decoding="async" src="https://example.com/epa/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/demo-9.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-3528"></figure>
```

The code editor code has no difference with normally upload images with srcset. So I assume there's nothing wrong on this part:

```html
<!-- wp:image {"id":3546,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img src="https://example.com/epa/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/demo-9.jpg" alt="this is a demo" class="wp-image-3546"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

Comment: WordPress should automatically add srcset when the post is rendered. Is there a reason you're trying to do it yourself?

Comment: Yeap, because I'm trying to replace an image block for another image I just upload programmatically.

Comment: And somehow, WordPress won't create the `srcset` attribute once I modify the block with the new path and publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue.

After uploading the image programmatically I was calling `wp_update_attachment_metadata` to set the `file` metadata.

Apparently, that was creating this issue and `srcset` was not being set.

I have no idea why this is related though :)